# Transaction State:6 in Test Credit Card Transaction.Amount is not credited in Sandbox BUSINESS Account

Tags: paypal, payflowlink

I made a test transaction using Test credit card number in PayPal payflow link.
Transaction status is below,
Transaction State:6
Response Code:A
Error Code:00
Amount is not credited in Sandbox BUSINESS Account.
I tried to find a solution with the help of error codes references.But couldn't get the solution.
Help me to complete the test transaction successfully.

Answer (score 0):

A transaction statu of 6 means that the thransaction has not settled, and that it is pending.  Are you using A payflow account that is connected to a Payflow account, or are you just using a Payflow account that is not connected to sandbox account.  Normally, it the account was connected to the sandbox it would settle, as it is host based and should settle in real time.  If you are using a test payflow account that is not connected to a sandbox account, and was using a 3rd party processor.  It would not actually settle out, it would rather show a trans state 6, but you should of gotten a result code of 0 back meaning it was successfully.  It would just remain in a trans state 6, because it would not really get passed on to the processor for processing.  If you still have questions, I can look into it further if you can provide the transaction id#.

Comment: Thanks for responding.Following is the transaction ID V78A3FF23FE0

Comment: I checked your transaction, and your account.  Your account is set up with a 3rd party processor for your direct credit card payments and set up with PayPal Express Checkout for PayPal payments.  So this is as I was saying before, since this is a 3rd party processor it will stay in trans state 6 and will not get passed on to the processor.  For testing, you would consider this as a successful transaction as it returned a result code 0.  There just isn't way to pass it on to the processor since its a test transaction.